# Cannot install Android Studio 1.4 on windows 7. Installer Integrity check error NSIS_Error?

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I install Android Studio IDE 1.4 in WQindows 7 or 8? The installer refuses to install saying that the Installer Integrity check failed.

Why am I facing NSIS_Error when I tried running it from Command Prompt using space/NCRC?

[image: error message]

Comment: Please let us know if you have found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says: `Common causes include incomplete download and damaged media` 
This most likely means that something went wrong during the download of the instillation file. Meaning the .exe is corrupt. Try re-downloading the Android studio.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

remove whatever you have of Android Studio on your computer and re-download and re-install. And since it's Windows restart a number of times.